# Do you have to change the REF HEAD when updating a file through Github's API

Tags: git, rest, api, github, github-api

For a project I am working I must be able to edit config files through a Web UI and then commit the changes to a GitHub repo. To do this I've been using **GitHub's API V3** to do this and actually got it working. However I am a little bit confused on how it works. From my understanding every time you make a commit to GitHub you must reference the new HEAD for the branch so the branch knows that is the most recent commit. But it seems to me that updating a file's content you do not need to do this. Can anybody explain to me why this is?